# Getting database in suspected mode while running DBCC checkdb command

Tags: sql-server-2012, dbcc

On production we had setup maintenance job for every weekend. In this maintenance job we use dbcc checkdb command in one of step. sometime while dbcc checkdb command run it gives database consistency error and database turn into suspected mode.

To fix the issue we followed below steps:

1. Restore new database from backup
2. Run DBCC checkdb repair command
3. It ran successfully without any error.

But we want to know why this issue is raised every 3 to 4 weeks? What is the cause behind this issue? It causes data loss every time it happens.

Comment: Thank you James Let me ask this question over there. But if you have idea how we can suspect hardware or driver issue?

Comment: What do your logs say?